# C# reading XML , how to get the value

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I am new to XML. Need some help.
I can get pro NAME fine but
How do I get the value of scode? JDK...blah

```
<pro NAME="JK1233k">
<scode ID="A">JDK-ORPLL-PDILL</scode>
</pro>


XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("file.xml");
while (reader.Read())
{
    if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "pro"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader["NAME"]);
    }
    else if((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "scode"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader["ID"]);
       //what do I put here to get the value????
    }
}
reader.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is:

```
Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadInnerXml());
```

---

I personally prefer LINQ to XML. If you haven't looked into it, you should. You can achieve the same thing in a cleaner manner.

at the start of your c# file put the following:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq; // loads the linq to xml part
```

Most XML files are much bigger than just one element. So for that, your code would be something like this:

```
// Load XML file as an IEnumerable. This allows you to query it.
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(file)
    .Elements("pro")
    .Select(pro => new
            {
                Name = pro.Attribute("NAME").Value,
                Scode = pro.Elements("scode").Select(scode => new
                {
                    ID = scode.Attribute("ID").Value,
                    Val = scode.Value
                })
            });

// loop through each <pro> element          
foreach (var pro in xmlDoc)
{
    // Get Pro Name
    Console.WriteLine(pro.Name);

    // loop through each <scode> element inside <pro>
    foreach(var scode in pro.Scode)
    {
        // Get Scode ID:
        Console.WriteLine(scode.ID);

        // Get Scode Value:
        Console.WriteLine(scode.Val);
    }
}
```

If your XML is only a **SINGLE** element, you can do this:

```
// Load XML file:
var pro = XElement.Load("file.xml");

// Get Pro Name
pro.Attribute("NAME").Value;

// Get Scode ID:
pro.Element("scode").Attribute("ID").Value;

// Get Scode Value:
pro.Element("scode").Value;
```

Comment: Please, don't use `Descendants` when you don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code snippet...

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("pro"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Attribute("NAME").Value);
}

foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("scode"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Value);
}
```

Good Luck!